# Mutate Variable to Create Yes/No with Pipes and User Defined Function

Tags: r, dplyr, user-defined-functions

I have a dozen variables that have are coded "0" or "1" corresponding to "No" and "Yes."  I'd like to rename the variables and recode them simultaneously. I can do this one by one using mutate and case_when:

```
> df$`*weight loss (dich)`
  [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [31] 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 [61] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
 [91] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
[121] 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
[151] 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

df %<>% 
    mutate(weight_loss = case_when(
      df$`*weight loss (dich)` == 0 ~ "No", 
      df$`*weight loss (dich)`  == 1 ~ "Yes"
    ))
```

I would like to write a function that performs the same action over multiple variables, given inputs where x = new name and y = old name. Here's my attempt, but it doesn't work:

```
> ynf <- function(x, y) {
+   df %<>% 
+     mutate(x = case_when(
+     y == 0 ~ "No", 
+     y == 1 ~ "Yes"
+   ))
+ }
> 
> ynf(weight_loss, df$`*weight loss (dich)`)
> 
> glimpse(df$weight_loss)
 NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'weight_loss'.
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I'd use `mutate_at/mutate_all`, here an example `mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(vs,am), list(new=~ifelse(.==1,"Yes","No")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the function to evaluate the 'x', 'y' and do the assignment `:=` to create the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
ynf <- function(x, y) {
 df %<>% 
    mutate(!! enquo(x) := case_when(
     {{y}} == 0 ~ "No", 
     {{y}} == 1 ~ "Yes"
     ))
    }

df <- ynf(weight_loss, `weight loss (dich)`)
glimpse(df)
#Rows: 20
#Columns: 2
#$ `weight loss (dich)` <int> 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
#$ weight_loss          <chr> "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No",…
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(`weight loss (dich)` = sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE),
            check.names = FALSE)
```